# Prevent simulator screenshot downsizing when window is downsized to fit monitor in xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm trying to get screenshots together for a new app version that I am going to submit. I'm using the ipad Pro 12.7 inch simulator in Xcode 9 to take these screenshots, but am running into an issue with the screenshots not being the right size for submittal.

In order to see the whole simulator's screen on my monitor I have to resize it's window. In doing this though, I noticed that it changes the resolution on the screenshots that are generated, making me unavailable to submit them since they don't meet the 2048 x 2732 pixels for portrait and are instead downsized.

I suppose I could manually adjust the resolution on every sceenshot, but surely there's a better way right? Anyone know of a work around for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure Debug > Optimize Rendering for Window Scale is disabled.

[image: Debug menu]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!  Was hoping on some off chance that would also fix MapKit being completely unusable in the iOS 11 simulators, but nope...  and didn't expect it would.  Regardless, I was starting to think I was going to have to fudge 12.9" screenshots, so thanks to both of you for asking & answering!